# Why does table SELECT become twice slower after restoring a db from 5.0.24 to 8.0.20?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I've got a new server so i had to configure MySQL on it, the **old server had installed MySQL 5.0.24** so i've done backup of my DBs and restored them on newly installed **MySQL 8.0.20 on the new server**..

First of all i've done some simple SELECT queryes to test the speed of old and new server and till here both were almost fast the same..

When the queryes become more **complex so with WHERE and GROUP BY** (test done on a **MyISAM** table), the **old server** was fetching almost 13000 rows from almost 3m table in **3s** while the **new server** with new MySQL was fetching the same rows in **21s** so i started to do some test like changing the table *from MyISAM to InnoDB* in the new server and after that and after setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 32G and i've got a fetch time of **9s** a better result than 21s but anyway three times slower than the old MySQL 5.0.24...

The query i'm testing is the following (the `WHERE` for NPV_SC and NCASSA_SC in this case select all rows):

```
SELECT 
    DESCRIZIONE_SC AS DESCRIZIONE,
    COUNT(DESCRIZIONE_SC) AS QTA,
    SUM(IMPORTO_SC) AS IMPORTO
FROM
    scontrini
WHERE
    (NPV_SC , NCASSA_SC) IN ((1 , 1) , (1 , 2),
        (1 , 2),
        (2 , 1),
        (2 , 2),
        (3 , 1),
        (4 , 1),
        (4 , 2),
        (5 , 1),
        (6 , 1),
        (6 , 2),
        (7 , 1),
        (10 , 1),
        (11 , 1),
        (12 , 1),
        (13 , 1),
        (16 , 1),
        (23 , 1),
        (24 , 1),
        (24 , 2),
        (108 , 1))
        AND DATA_SC BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2020-05-07'
GROUP BY DESCRIZIONE_SC
ORDER BY IMPORTO_SC DESC;
```

So the query above equals to:

```
SELECT 
    DESCRIZIONE_SC AS DESCRIZIONE,
    COUNT(DESCRIZIONE_SC) AS QTA,
    SUM(IMPORTO_SC) AS IMPORTO
FROM
    scontrini
WHERE DATA_SC BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2020-05-07'
GROUP BY DESCRIZIONE_SC
ORDER BY IMPORTO_SC DESC;
```

Which still has same execution time

**UPDATED: the above queries has changed after suggestion in comments on how to set the WHERE but anyway the fetch time is 5 seconds VS 3/2.80 seconds of old server with MySQL 5.0.24 (so the fetch time by optimizing the WHERE changed from 9s to 5 but still "far" from the old MySQL..)**

The index are on NPV_SC, NCASSA_SC, DATA_SC, DESCRIZIONE_SC and IMPORTO_SC

Here is the create statment (without insignificant columns that was like other 10)

```
CREATE TABLE `scontrini` (
  `NPV_SC` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NCASSA_SC` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TIPODOC_SC` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DATA_SC` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2001-01-01',
  `AZZ_SC` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  `NSC_SC` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ID_SC` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DESCRIZIONE_SC` varchar(250) DEFAULT '',
  `IMPORTO_SC` float(10,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`NPV_SC`,`NCASSA_SC`,`TIPODOC_SC`,`DATA_SC`,`AZZ_SC`,`NSC_SC`,`ID_SC`),
  KEY `PIUMENOVEN` (`NPV_SC`,`NCASSA_SC`,`DATA_SC`),
  KEY `REP` (`REPARTO_SC`),
  KEY `RC` (`RC_SC`),
  KEY `MENU` (`MENU_SC`),
  KEY `idx_scontrini_IMPORTO_SC` (`IMPORTO_SC`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `idx_scontrini_DESCRIZIONE_SC` (`DESCRIZIONE_SC`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the explain

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys                                   | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | scontrini | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY,PIUMENOVEN,idx_scontrini_DESCRIZIONE_SC | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2483404 | 11.11    | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

[image]

The server has `64GB Ram, 1.5TB os SSD and 10x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 @ 2.20GHz`

[Here](https://github.com/nicetomytyuk/mysql/blob/master/my.ini) is my my.ini hosted on github

Comment: Replace your `OR` bunch with `WHERE (NPV_SC, NCASSA_SC) IN ((1,1), (1,2), (2,1), ... (108,1))`. Do not use quoting for literals in integer conditions - this converts them into strings. Ensure that the index `PIUMENOVEN` is used (does this query selects less than 5% of table records?).

Comment: @Akina i've just added the screens from explain and it seems that PIUMENOVEN is used..

Comment: *i've just added the screens from explain* This is NOT `EXPLAIN` - it must be table-formatted text. Do not use visual tools, get EXPLAIN using CLI. *it seems that PIUMENOVEN is used* I see fullscan and do not see index usage.

Comment: @Akina added the explain in table-format, but actually if i check "Query Stats" it's saying that `Index Usadge: No Index Used`.. anyway by trying the where without all OR the fetch time become from 9s to 6s so still twice slower than MySQL 5.0.24

Comment: Try to force index usage (but remember that this can both help and hinder).

Comment: @Akina by setting explicitly USE INDEX (PIUMENOVEN) fetch time become 5s.. but anyway i can't get why that difference between two versions and i even had to change table from MyISAM to InnoDB as it was even more slow when on old MySQL it was ok..

Comment: what about other MySQL Server configuration parameters? for example, temp table size

Comment: @Nikita added my.ini the temp_table_size is set to 4G

Comment: you need to increase max_heap_table_size too

Comment: is there date range a small part of the data table? if so an index `DATA_SC, NPV_SC , NCASSA_SC, DESCRIZIONE_SC` might help. Is `IMPORTO_SC` the intentional order by column? Or are you ordering by the sum `IMPORTO`?

Comment: @danblack the table has 2.4m rows, the selected data range has only 14k rows, the index for `DATA_SC, NPV_SC, NCASSA_SC` is yet created and called `PIUMENOVEN` with index type `BTREE` and unique set to NO, and yea i'm ordering the sum importo

Comment: @danblack actually in that table even if i do a simple select where i set a specific date it scan the whole table...

Comment: the order of the elements in the index matters significantly

Comment: @danblack actually by changing the order from setting data as first the filtered result now is 50% (1st it was 11%) but fetch time is almost the same (4.50s)

Comment: Perhaps you meant `ORDER BY IMPORTO DESC`, not `ORDER BY IMPORTO_SC DESC` ?

Comment: Additional information request. From your MySQL Host server, post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) complete MySQLTuner report AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, ulimit -a for a Linux/Unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor, you may find this workaround improves your speed on your MySQL 8.0.20 instance

SET GLOBAL internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine=MEMORY;

Refer to dba.stackexchange.com Question 267143 and look for Shane Bester's mention with the bug report.  You will discover this was an error in 8.0.20, that will be corrected when 8.0.21 becomes available.  Make this change to your my.ini as well to be in place after stop/start of your 8.0.20 instance.

Comment: yea damn even after optimizing the query as suggested by Rick James that was taking (2s to execute the query) by setting internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine=MEMORY it take now 0.02s. thank you!

Comment: View my profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to also improve performance tuning.

Answer (score 1):

Add both of these; see which one it likes:

```
INDEX(data_sc, descrizione_sc, importo_sc)
INDEX(descrizione_sc, data_sc, importo_sc)
```

You provided `EXPLAIN` for one server; was the other one identical?

> (the WHERE for NPV_SC and NCASSA_SC in this case select all rows):

All rows?  Useless.  Why even discuss NPV_SC, NCASSA_SC if you are not filtering on them?

> WHERE  (NPV_SC , NCASSA_SC) IN ((1 , 1) , (1 , 2), ... )

Before 5.7, "row constructors" were not optimized at all.  Afterward, it does some optimization; maybe that misdirects the optimizer.  In particular, the Optimizer will not discover that that list is the entire table.

> tmp_table size and max_heap_table_size = 4G

Dangerously high.  Don't go over about 1% of RAM.

The change from MyISAM to InnoDB -- this will increase the disk footprint by between 2x and 3x (usually).

Did you turn off the "query cache" and run each timing test twice?

What does "3/2.80" mean?

Comment: By checking the explain on the old server, it wasn't using at all the index 'PIUMENOVEN' the possible keys is just null, 3/2.80 means that on fresh query execute it takes 3 seconds and reexecuted 2.80 seconds. i'd now try with indexes you suggested, by changing tmp_table and by turning off query cache

Comment: And the NPV_SC and NCASSA_SC has been discussed as it's a "standart" for that query, it's like a filter of which "shop and it's operator" get the data, the user on front end can check like shop 1 and it's operator 1 and 2 and by default all shops are selected

Comment: After trying the two index you suggested, the query got the 1st one and by testing it 1 by 1 the 1st was faster, i've added to the index the NPV and NCASSA after importo and hell yeah now the query execution time is 1.92 seconds

Comment: but at this point how the hell could MySQL 5.0.24 that wasn't using any Index could be that fast versus MySQL 8? (i'm talking about when i've just imported the db so the table was MyISAM on both servers but on the old one the query execute time was 3 seconds and on MySQL 8 of 31 seconds)

Comment: @IgorMytyuk - `INDEX` usage may not have changed between 5.0 and 8.0 _for this use case_.  InnoDB has had a lot of development since 5.0, but MyISAM has had zero development.

Comment: @IgorMytyuk - And...  There may be other factors that haven't been adequately adjusted -- `key_buffer_size`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  Etc.  My two suggested indexes are "covering".  That, alone, would help in either engine and in either version.